# Remove only the input elements in the List in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having a list  like

```
     <li style="display: list-item;" id="listChoices">
      <label class="topspace">Enter the Choices</label>
    <input value="Choice1" maxlength="150" id="Choice1"/>
   <input value="Choice2" maxlength="150" id="Choice2"/>
   <input value="Choice3" maxlength="150" id="Choice3"/>

     </li>
```

I want to delete the input tag alone so i tried it with

$("#listChoices").empty(); // which removes the entire content of the list .
But i want to remove only the input elements so i tried it with

```
    $("#listChoices input").empty();//But its not working..Why so???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 $("#listChoices input").remove();
```

Which will remove the tags. `empty()` will simply clear the innerHTML.

Comment: Ah, was a tad bit too slow :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all the input elements after the label. Then use this.

`$('.topspace').nextAll().remove()`.